# Defining own command in command mode with :

Tags: vim

I want to define a command that is executed by `:command<CR>`.

I tried something like this:

```
cmap hello exec "normal aHello World"<Esc>
```

I have two problems with the result:

1. If I type slowly, then there sits `:hello` in the bottom line, and after pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>, I get

   > Not an editor command: hello
2. If I type fast then `:hello` doesn’t sit there and it doesn't wait for me to hit the <kbd>Return</kbd> key – but at least it works.

Can somebody please points out to me how I have to define the `hello` command in a way that typing slowly will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've always written colon-mode commands in vim is like this:

```
command! BASH !start bash
```

note the command must be in uppercase.

Comment: Only first letter must be uppercase.

Comment: after defining command as in the answer you can use cmap to use lower case: cmap bash BASH<CR>